# How should I pass a restricted class instance

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

With OOP what is the recommended way to pass an instance of a class which is restricted - such as read-only properties or less methods available.

Below is a `Vector2`, which contains multiple methods for manipulating it's properties such as the setters or the `add` function.

```
class Vector2 {
  private _x: number = 0;
  private _y: number = 0;

  public get x () {
    return this._x;
  }

  public get y () {...}

  public set x (x: number) {
    this._x = x;
  }

  public set y (y: number) {...}

  public add (v: Vector2) {
    this._x += v.x;
    this._y += v.y;
  }
}
```

How would I pass a restricted version of this instance, for example a read-only `Vector2` with only the getters available. The solution I've had is to create another seperate class I'll name `Vector2RO` which wraps around a `Vector2` but I feel like there could be a "better" or more "elegant" way to do so.

```
class Vector2RO {
  private _v: Vector2;

  public constructor (v: Vector2) {
    this._v = v;
  }

  public get x () {
    return this._v.x;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could define an interface Vector2RO, and have Vector2 implement that interface, extending it with mutators. Then, you can reasonably pass around the Vector2RO object.

Comment: Nothing significantly more elegant. You have several options. You either (1) wrap the object like that (but then you have to be careful that something doesn't change the wrapped instance unintentionally), (2) return a copy of the vector to a client that requests it, and then it's their business (works well if copying the object is cheap), or (3) work exclusively with immutable objects (once you construct it, it cannot be changed; if you want different coordinates, you have to create another instance; again, works well if constructing the objects is cheap).

Comment: P.S. BTW, implementing a read-only interface is similar to my case (1) in the comment above (works, but have to be careful, as client code can cast the object to its actual type). It is a less work then writing a wrapper, though.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović the integration segregation principle would have you create an interface narrowed down to what the client actually uses anyway. Whether that's enough depends on how hostile you consider the other coders.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - Copying the object is not an option in my case, I've ended up creating a wrapper class.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: Yeah, that's true. I was listing pros and cons, but their impact depends on the context. If the design decisions are communicated well among the members of a team, then you can tone down on defensive programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, I'd just use a `const` reference. In languages without such type qualifiers, a decorator or wrapper like you suggested is the standard approach. I know of similar examples in Python or Java.

It's important to spend some thought on the relation between a readonly wrapper and the mutable object. Should they share an interface? The fact is that the mutable object will also implement all the methods that are part of the readonly interface. So it might make sense to have `Vector2` implement the `Vector2ReadOnly` inteface. On the other hand, the `Vector2` is *not* read-only, and implementing such an interface would be highly misleading.

My recommendation would be to avoid inheritance, and instead use a completely independent class for the read-only wrapper. Alternatively, the interface should make it clear that the object is not immutable, but that this interface merely contains the getters or the read-only *part* of the interface. `Vector2Getters` might be an accurate though rather awkward name.

Comment: Avoiding inheritance with an independant class is what I've ended up doing.